# How to indicate that something is in the shape of 'finger'?

Tags: phrases

For example

> Kofta can be made in ball shape and *finger* shape as the shape of regular sausage.

Is the 'finger' shape correct here?

Comment: It works for me.  Less likely to be questioned: in the shape of a finger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it happens, the usual English expression for something shaped like a link sausuage is *[sausage-shaped](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sausage-shaped)*. Princeton Wordnet defines it tautologically as "shaped like a sausage," and under the entry *sausage*, this shape is given as "cyclindrical."

Naturally, this is unhelpful when comparing different shapes of meat. Some dictionaries describe *sausage* as *tube-shaped* meat. *[Hot dog](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Hotdogs.JPG)-shaped* (or *frankfurter-shaped*) is another alternative.

While *finger-shaped* is a possible analogy, *fingers* carries connotations of something short and slender; consider that [okra](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Lady_finger_close_up.jpg) and [a type of baked sweet](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Biskotten-02.jpg) are known as *lady fingers*. For something round but tapered at the ends, *cigar-shaped* is common, though less often with food than with, for example, [unidentified flying objects](http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/nasas-curiosity-rover-captures-cigar-shaped-ufo-orbiting-mars-1448451).

Yet another possibility is the shape of a *stick*. This is somewhat less satisfactory as it invites confusion with kebabs or various kinds of stick meat and meat sticks, but it would be understood if the phrasing were explicit enough:

> Kofta can be shaped into meatballs or into sticks.
>
> Kofta can be made into ball-shaped or tube-shaped lumps.
>
> Kofta can be shaped into round or cylindrical pieces.
>
> Kofta can be made in the shape of a golf ball or in the shape of a cigar.